# representing CIs in hierarchical arima forecast (HTS in R)

Tags: r, visualization, forecasting, arima

My query is how to get confidence interval of forecast line to display as part of the plot produced with hts.

I am not sure whether this feature is directly available in hts - if not, it'd be immensely helpful to pointed toward a suitable workaround. Not very familiar with autoplot, but have run into problems trying to use it in conjunction with hts.

I am fairly new to forecast modelling so any tips regarding the standard procedures / modes visualisation employed to express uncertainty would be much appreciated. For instance, the metrics calculated at bottom of this code block seem to present a common-sense evaluation of the model.

```
#Preprocessing

hierarchystructure <- list(20, c(3, 5, 53, 6, 4, 3, 3, 10, 2, 6, 4, 2, 8, 6, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3))

# Create  hierarchical time series spanning 1990 - 2021
hierarchical_ts <- hts(multivariate_ts, nodes = hierarchystructure)

# Forecast 'future' values (2022 - 2026)
forecast_values <- forecast(hierarchical_ts, fmethod = "arima", h = 5, method = "comb", weights = "ols", algorithm = "lu")
plot(forecast_values)

# investigating accuracy via comparison of true 2017-2021 values with model estimates of 2017 - 2021 when that period is held out

trial <- window(hierarchical_ts, start = 1991, end = 2016)
test <-  window(hierarchical_ts, start = 2017)
fcasts <- forecast(trial, h = 5, method = "comb", weights = "ols", algorithm = "lu")
accuracies <- t(accuracy(fcasts, test, levels = c(0, 1, 2)))
```

Comment: The `hts` package does not produce prediction intervals. The `ForeReco` package does what you want.